# return top 5 value using vector iterator

Tags: c++, vector

Hi all is there any way to return the first 5 element in a vector using vector iterator?

In this example I've got it will only all value in the vector itself.

```
// vector::begin/end
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main ()
{
  std::vector<int> myvector;
  for (int i=1; i<=10; i++) myvector.push_back(i);

  std::cout << "myvector contains:";
  for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = myvector.begin() ; it != myvector.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << ' ' << *it;
  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

hmmm thanks for all the prompt reply.. but why am I having compilation error when I try to put them in a function?

```
void Test::topfives()
{   
    topfive.assign( point1.begin(), point1.end() ); 
    sort(topfive.begin(), topfive.end(), sortByCiv);
}

void Test::DisplayTopFiveResult()
{
    test.topfives();

    copy(topfive.begin(), topfive.begin()+ min(topfive.size(), (size_t )5),
    ostream_iterator<Level>(cout << level.displayClassresult()));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Advance the `myvector.begin()` by 5

```
std::copy(myvector.begin(), 
          myvector.begin()+std::min(myvector.size(), (size_t)5), 
          std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout,"\n"));
```

This prints at max top 5 elements from `myvector`

See [***Here***](http://ideone.com/tTDYU5)

Ref: - [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy), [`std::min`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min), and [`std::ostream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator)

Comment: myvector.begin() + min(myvector.size(), 5)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main ()
{
  std::vector<int> myvector;
  for (int i=1; i<=10; i++) myvector.push_back(i);

  std::cout << "myvector contains:";
  std::vector<int>::iterator it = myvector.begin()
  for (int i = 0; i < 5 && it != myvector.end(); i++) {
    std::cout << ' ' << *it;
    ++it;
  }
  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

std::vector supports [random access iterators](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/RandomAccessIterator.html), which means you can do this:

```
myvector.begin() + 5
```

So two options for your code:

```
std::cout << "myvector contains:";
size_t maxElements = std::min(myvector.size(), size_t(5));
for (size_t i = 0; i < numElements; ++i) {
  std::cout << ' ' << myvector[i];
```

or

```
auto startIt = myvector.begin();
auto endIt = myvector.begin() + 5;
for (auto it = startIt; it != endIt; ++it)
  std::cout << ' ' << *it;
```

Comment: `std::min(myvector.size(), (size_t )5),`

Comment: @P0W Clearly I am getting lazy in my old age :) Fixed, thanks :)

Comment: "Because of the way a vector is implemented". No, it's because of the *interface*, not the implementation.

Comment: @P0W hi P0W i've just updated the question.. cause whenever i try to compile it using my own function it gives me compilation error.

Comment: @koi_s3ng you need to overload `<<` for your class `MissionPlan`, also you are using `std::ostsream_iterator` incorrectly. You should better post this as new question, but please look on SO for related issue